# sfValidatorRegex with multiple patterns in symfony

Tags: php, regex, symfony1

I have this bit of code implemented with symfony:

```
$p1 = '/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i';
$p2 = '/^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i';

$this->setValidators(array(
 ...
 'field_1' => new sfValidatorRegex(
          array('pattern' => p1.'|'.p2)),
```

...

The field_1 must match either pattern p1 or p2, but it doesn't work.
Any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You concatenate the delimiters and flags, that doesn't work.

Try:

```
$p1 = '(?i:^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$)';
$p2 = '(?i:^[XYZ][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$)';

$this->setValidators(array(
 ...
 'field_1' => new sfValidatorRegex(
          array('pattern' => "/$p1|$p2/")),
```

Also in your case you can just use a pattern like:

```
$re = '/^[XYZ0-9][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$/i';
```

Comment: or use 2 seperate `sfValidatorRegex` in combination with `sfValidatorOr`

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. I didn't want to use two sfValidatorRegex combined with sfValidatorOr cause it throws two invalid messages if an error has occured.